# Transform and use all variables matching a pattern in a rule

Tags: makefile, build

In a Makefile imagine that I have a rule that treats a group of variables in the same, way, e.g., by passing their value as a define of the same name to a compilation target, e.g.,:

```
CC $(CXXFLAGS) ... -DFOO_BAR=$(FOO_BAR) -DFOO_BAZ=$(FOO_BAZ) ...
```

Regardless of whether this is a good design, is there some way to generalize this so all variables with the form `FOO_*` are passed in this way?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `-DFOO_BAZ=$(FOO_BAZ)` in the second instance, not `$(FOO_BAR)`

Comment: @mad - yes, fixed. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using GNU make, you can do something like this:

```
FOODEFS = $(foreach F,$(filter FOO_%,$(.VARIABLES)),-D$F=$($F))

        CC $(CXXFLAGS) ... $(FOODEFS) ...
```